# Laravel Eloquent get data where comparison is true

Tags: laravel, eloquent, voyager

I am creating a mini inventory stock for a fashion store. I am using Laravel/Voyager with BREAD and everything fine. I have 2 tables `Sizes` and `Products` with a column in common `product_code`.

I would like to get the results from `Sizes` where column `product_code` = `Product 'product_code'`.
I have this query in the controller:

```
$product_code = Product::all();
$allSizes = Size::where('product_code', ($product_code->product_code));
```

and in browse.blade.php I have:

```
@foreach ($allSizes as $size)
    <tr>
        <td align="right">{{$size->size_name}}</td>
        <td align="right">{{$size->stock}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I guess the `where` statement is not working as supposed to. 
I want to get the corresponding `stock` based on `product_code` for each size from table `Sizes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
$product_code = Product::pluck('product_code')->toArray();
$allSizes = Size::whereIn('product_code', $product_code)->get();
```

and in browse.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($allSizes as $size)
    <tr>
        <td align="right">{{$size->size_name}}</td>
        <td align="right">{{$size->stock}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Or you can ask for join also

Comment: is throwing bac error `Trying to get property 'product_code' of non-object `

Comment: Check It now @fallcoshkoder

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Your tables are **related** in some way and you need to define a **relationship** to access the data *Eloquent*ly.

If I were building such a database, I think that the relationship between `Product` and `Size` is a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).  I.e. a `Product` can have many `Size`s, and you can also shop for many `Product`s in a certain `Size`.  Thus, your models should have a `belongsToMany()` relationship to each other.

```php
// Product.php
protected $with = ['sizes'];     // eager load product sizes
public function sizes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class);
}

// Size.php
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Then you can do

```php
// ProductsController.php
public function show(Product $product) {
    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to run the `query`

```php
$product_code = Product::all();
# ::all() will return collection, and you can't access a property of it directly

$allSizes = Size::where('product_code', ($product_code->first()->product_code))->get();
```

> Notice the ->get();

Comment: Ye noticed that. but now I get an error `Property [product_code] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: check my updated answer, youre returning Product::all(); which will return a collection, so you can't do this $product_code->product_code, betcause $product_code is a collection, you need to pick a single value

Comment: Understood, but as you say "can't do this $product_code->product_code, betcause $product_code is a collection" I have the product_code as a variable. the SQL statement I am trying to get is: `SELECT * FROM sizes WHERE product_code=$product_code;` then elaborate the data to get the sizes of each product and stock of each size.